# Unable to create .exe using GraalVM docker image in Windows

Tags: spring-boot, docker, intellij-idea, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

In **Windows 10** environment, with **IntelliJ Idea**, I have a sample **Spring Boot** application created with *bootify*, called **Bootifytwo**, which is located in the **C:\CODIGO\IDEA_PROJECTS\bootifytwo** folder.

In the **pom.xml** of said application I have the following **dependency** configured:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

My intention is, using **GraalVM**, to get to generate the **bootifytwo.exe** and be able to run it correctly.

To do this, I have downloaded the following **Docker image** with GraalVM from the **Oracle repositories**; and performed the following commands:

```
docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm/community:ol8-java17-22.3.0-b1

docker images

docker run -it --rm container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm/community:ol8-java17-22.3.0-b1 bash

java -version

gu install native-image

native-image --version
```

Everything is working fine until I try to change to my project folder.

[image: terminal screenshot]

As long as I can´t change to my project folder (**cd C:\CODIGO\IDEA_PROJECTS\bootifytwo**) I can't create the .exe with the following:

**`.\mvnw native:compile -Pnative`**

And finally locate myself in the target folder (**cd C:\CODIGO\IDEA_PROJECTS\bootifytwo\target**) and launch the desired **bootifytwo.exe**

I would appreciate help in this complex path. (I don't know if I need to define the **GRAALVM_HOME** variable, or map a **volume**...)

Comment: It seems `native-image` is not included in this docker image, does `gu install native-image` help?

Comment: Yo are right. Now I am able to launch 'native-image --version'.

Comment: I edited original post to better reflect actual situation

Comment: You're now inside a Docker image, which has its own filesystem separate from the host filesystem. Plus it's a Linux image, so you should be using Linux paths (`/home/user/` etc). Or you might want to skip the Docker thing altogether, just install a Windows GraalVM package, run `gu install native-image` and build your app right on the host system

Comment: Previously I tried this way of directly installing GraalVM for Windows. I was able to generate the .exe but when I ran it it failed. That's why I'm trying this second way with Docker.

Comment: On the other hand cd /CODIGO/IDEA_PROJECTS/bootifytwo also failed. I think you might need to map something to the host-docker filesystem... set a volume

Answer (score 0):

The solution to generate the .exe was:

Copy the app folder to (future) volume destination:

In my case:
C:\CODIGO\IDEA_PROJECTS\bootifytwo to C:\Volumenes-Docker\vol-graalvm-one\bootifytwo

Then launch the following commands:

```
docker run --name container-graalvm-one -v "C:\Volumenes-Docker\vol-graalvm-one:/app" -it container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm/community:ol8-java17-22.3.0-b1 bash

gu install native-image

cd bootifytwo

. ./mvnw native:compile -Pnative
```

[image: successful build]

[image: not an exe file]

Then, I was able to launch the app with:

```
./bootifytwo
```

But fails in the connection with my DB (that also was "inside" another docker/postgres container)

[image]